# Managing previous updates to Fedora

Tags: fedora, software-updates

When Fedora boots, I am offered several older versions of the current main version. Sometimes, after a *sudo dnf update*,  I get a version that breaks something important.  At that point I usually try rebooting to an older version (selected at start-up) and if that reboot restores functionality, I am (temporarily) happy.

So let's say I perform another dnf update the next day and get another version that still breaks my machine. So again I reboot to that previous version that works (happy again).

However, one cannot do this forever as eventually the working (older) version falls off the list and I end up only being able to choose versions that have the problem.

Is there a way to either "lock" an older version onto the list, or extend the length of the list so that the working version stays available?  Or some other "fix"?

Answer (score 1):

To keep older kernel version (that's what you can choose at start-up) you can:

1. Lock specific kernel version

First list all installed kernels with

`rpm -qa kernel\*`

command and choose version you want to keep. Then lock that kernel using `dnf mark install` command like this:

```
dnf mark install kernel-4.18.9-200.fc28.x86_64
```

2. Set the number of older kernels to keep

To make it you can use dnf configuration option `installonly_limit`, which is set in the [main] section of `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf` file. Default value is 3. You can choose to keep more installonly packages (which include kernels) by using a greater number, e.g.

```
installonly_limit=5
```

or keep all installed kernel by setting `installonly_limit` to zero. Note that if you choose to keep all old kernels they can take quite a lot of disk space.

You can read more here:

[DNF mark command](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#mark-command-label)

[DNF installonly_limit](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conf_ref.html#installonly-limit-label)